# Android Expandable listview like Gmail threads

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to show an expandable list view like Gmail which having multiple threads in an Email. I am trying to add a header in the expandable list by referring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046055/how-to-insert-header-row-on-expandable-list-view)

Here is the expected format to show:
[image]

When we click on the count of it for ex. 8 from the screenshot it should show all the threads present in that email.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following library or you can add just few classes from it to achieve your requirements

[Sectioned Recyclerview](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter)

Comment: I am already using it for another purpose and this is just for showing more item in the list, here the requirement is just like Gmail as shown in the screenshot. But by using this we can't achieve above.